# Weird Display issue: strange behavior and can't roll back to prior kernels

Tags: unity, mouse

This seems like a display software issue.

As of this morning, Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) automatically switches to the first tab when I try to select a different tab or open a new tab.  If I open a new tab the active tab cycles across all open tabs one by one until the first tab (left most) is active.

I'm running kernel 3.13.0-68-generic on 14.04.3 LTS

I have uninstalled Chrome using apt-get purge and reinstalled.  I'm seeing the same behavior.

In Firefox tabs work but drop downs are acting funky, automatically switching when I mouse over.  I'm seeing the funky drop down behavior throughout the system.  I can't make selections with the mouse.

I have tried disabling all chrome extensions.  I killed any apps that affect the display such as unclutter and redshift.

Switching tabs after launching with `google-chrome-stable --enable-logging=stderr`  I'm not seeing anything in the console when the behavior occurs.

How else can I troubleshoot this issue?

EDIT:  I have tried rolling back to other kernels with unexpected results.   Rolling back to 3.2.0-67 I can't login.  I get the lightdm login screen and can enter my credentials but the desktop never appears.  I get the lightdm login screen again.

I tried rolling back to 3.13.67 and 3.13.66 and 3.13.65 and no network or usb devices work.  I get to the lightdm login screen but can not interact via keyboard or mouse or ssh.

I installed 3.16.53 and saw the same results, no access to the machine.

I addition to the strange behavior I already described, I am seeing other odd behavior which makes the machine difficult to use.  In one case a webapp that displays stock charts starts scrolling when I mouse over when it should not do anything.  This is my first major issue using Ubuntu since I switched 3 years ago.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here are a list of recent installs and upgrades since before the issue started http://paste.ubuntu.com/13300434/

EDIT: I just tested my system with a live usb running Ubuntu 15.10 and I am seeing similar results with the mouse.  If i hold the mouse over a tab in Chrome, Chrome will cycle through the tabs.  If I hold mouse over a dropdown the values will change without clicking.  I'm using an Anker bluetooth mouse.

Comment: Do you have esternal repositories active? Do you have official testing repositories (aka proposed) enabled?

Comment: I do have external repos for chrome, node, audacity, thunderbird, dropbox, google music manager, neovim, insync, heroku, libreoffice, spotify, java, virtualbox,freecad.  None of these were recently added.

Comment: Did you update something recently (this morning/yesterday)?

Comment: No configuration changes. Only normal software updates from the repositories. I do believe there was the upgrade to the most recent kernel before this issue occurred. My computer has an Intel graphics processor.

Comment: What were the updates exactly? I believe too that there was an update, but I am not entirely sure that it is related to the kernel.

Comment: I will make a list and update the question when I get back to my computer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great, let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit here was a wireless bluetooth mouse.  I plugged in a usb mouse and the issue went away.  I'm going to order a new mouse.  This one is a few years old.

Comment: New wireless mouse arrived and as suspected, everything is back to normal